# How would I make this code more compact/efficient?

Tags: r, loops

I apologize for asking a simple question, but I am trying to learn for the first time how to use for-loops in R and am not having a lot of luck generalizing what any of the guides have shown me to my specific problem (or in general!) I need to make a lot (~18) of different distributions from expert opinion and can do it by adding triangle distributions together. However, the code isn't very good, and I think it could be improved maybe using a for loop but I'm not sure how - especially since all of the min/max/mode estimates are different. How could I improve this? (Code below for just one of 18 distributions):

```
library(mc2d)
x <- seq(from=0.5, to=6, by=0.001)
june.cool <- dtriang(x, min=1,   max=2, mode=1)   +
             dtriang(x, min=1,   max=4, mode=2)   +
             dtriang(x, min=0.5, max=1, mode=1)   +
             dtriang(x, min=2,   max=4, mode=3)   +
             dtriang(x, min=0.25,max=1, mode=1)   +   
             dtriang(x, min=1,   max=3, mode=2)   +
             dtriang(x, min=0.5, max=2, mode=1)   +
             dtriang(x, min=1,   max=5, mode=2.5) +
             dtriang(x, min=1,   max=6, mode=4)
```

Comment: @Hugh - I'm guessing a function from this package: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mc2d/docs/qpert

Comment: You should add all package dependencies.

Comment: Hi Hugh - thelatemail is right, it's an alternative to the triangle distribution for modeling expert opinion. I just edited question since triangle distribution is more familiar.

Comment: How are the max/mins/modes changing between distributions? What is exactly changing here? Does x remain the same?

Comment: Yes - so for each overall distribution (in this case I've only shown one, "june.cool") the x should remain the same. It's just an arbitrary vector going from the min to the max to run the density function. Each individual dtriang has a different min/max/mode because it was one expert's opinion on the parameters. So in this case, for min=1, max=2, and mode=1, that was one person's estimate of how long it took to get a product cooled down in the month of June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (done only for the first three distributions)

```
values <- data.frame(min = c(1,1,0.5),
                     max = c(2,4,1),
                     mode = c(1,2,1))

june.cool <- eval(parse(text=paste(apply(values, 1, function(my.row)
               sprintf("dtriang(x, min=%f, max=%f, mode=%f) ",
                   my.row["min"], my.row["max"], my.row["mode"])),
           collapse = " + ")
))
```

starting from a data.frame of specified distribution parameters, create the expression by single statements and `paste`ing all together, then evaluate it and assign it to `june.cool`

Comment: This is just the kind of thing I was looking for! There are a lot of commands in here I don't recognize so I'll have fun looking them up :) I wish I could figure out how to do this on my own but I guess it comes with more R experience. Thanks Luca

Comment: I didn't knew Map, but I think @Neal 's way is surely nicer than mine! (yes I do love intellectual honesty :)  ) some other times (eg inside for loops), i found useful the `eval(parse(text=foo))` trick

Answer (score 4):

Riffing on @Luca's answer, I would use apply and rowSums:

```
 rowSums(  apply(values, 1, function(args) dtriang(x, min=args[1],
                                                max=args[2],
                                                mode=args[3])
                                        ))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally better to work with the language, rather than character strings that are pasted together and evaluated. The experts say:

```
xprt <- data.frame(min=c(1, 1, .5, 2, .25, 1, .5, 1, 1),
                   max=c(2, 4, 1, 4, 1,3, 2, 5, 6),
                   mode=c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2.5, 4))
```

You'd like to `Map`, using `dtriang`, each row to a new value, with an additional argument (constant across rows) `x`, so

```
val <- with(xprt, Map(dtriang, min=min, max=max, mode=mode, MoreArgs=list(x=x)))
```

This gives a list of results, and you'd like to reduce them to a single value by summing them up

```
Reduce(`+`, val)
```

Combined:

```
with(xprt, {
    Reduce(`+`, Map(dtriang, min=min, max=max, mode=mode, MoreArgs=list(x=x)))
})
```

Comment: Hi Martin - you say work with the language - what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The answer that you selected creates a _character string_ representing the expression to be evaluated, and then evaluates it. In contrast, the answer from @NealFultz and my answer work directly with the _symbols_ that reference the values you wish to transform.